# How to hide tables inside divs initially then show/hide tables based on clicks

Tags: javascript, html

The following is an example code in my index.php file.

```
<h3 class='anime-button btn'>Anime</h3>
<div class='anime'>
    <?php $type = "ANIME"; ?>
    <h3 class='current-anime-button btn'>Currently watching anime</h3>
    <div class='current-anime'>
        <?php
        $status = "CURRENT";
        try {
            $data = get_userList($userId, $type, $status);
        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cover</th>
                    <th>Anime</th>
                    <th>Progress</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                    $html = "<tr><td><a href='https://anilist.co/anime/" . $data[$i]['media']['id'] . "' target='_blank'><img src='" . $data[$i]['media']['coverImage']['large'] . "' alt='cover'></a></td>";
                    $html .= "<td>" . $data[$i]['media']['title']['romaji'] . "</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>" . $data[$i]['progress'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo $html;
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <h3 class='completed-anime-button btn'>Completed anime</h3>
    <div class='completed-anime'>
        <?php
        $status = "COMPLETED";
        try {
        $data = get_userList($userId, $type, $status);
        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cover</th>
                    <th>Anime</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                    $html = "<tr><td><a href='https://anilist.co/anime/" . $data[$i]['media']['id'] . "' target='_blank'><img src='" . $data[$i]['media']['coverImage']['large'] . "' alt='cover'></a></td>";
                    $html .= "<td>" . $data[$i]['media']['title']['romaji'] . "</td>";
                    $html .= "<td>" . $data[$i]['score'] . "</td></tr>";
                    echo $html;
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is an example code from my script.js file.

```
const animeButton = document.querySelector('.anime-button');
const currentAnimeButton = document.querySelector('.current-anime-button');
const completedAnimeButton = document.querySelector('.completed-anime-button');

let anime = document.querySelector('.anime');
let currentAnime = document.querySelector('.current-anime');
let completedAnime = document.querySelector('.completed-anime');

anime.style.display = 'none';
currentAnime.style.display = 'none';
completedAnime.style.display = 'none';

animeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (anime.style.display === 'none') {
        anime.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        anime.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    currentAnimeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (currentAnime.style.display === 'none') {
            currentAnime.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            currentAnime.style.display = 'none';
        }
        completedAnime.style.display = 'none';
    });

    completedAnimeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        currentAnime.style.display = 'none';
        if (completedAnime.style.display === 'none') {
            completedAnime.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            completedAnime.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

My questions are how do I hide the `anime`, `current-anime` and `completed-anime` divs initially (i.e. immediately after I log in), and how do I show or hide the divs depending on which `h3` element I click? Everything worked fine before I added the table elements inside the divs. Are these not possible with tables?

Comment: You've got 2 event listeners nested inside another event listener. So every time a click event happens on `animeButton` you're attaching event listeners to `currentAnimeButton` and `completedAnimeButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. The trick was to place the entire table inside an if-block for `current-anime` and `completed-anime` (and others which I haven't included in my post).